# Table view crashes when I click on TableView cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am getting a crash (app quits in iOS simulator) when I click on a cell. The error code is

> "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address= 0x310cc493)

Here is the code:

```
// .h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ChecklistsViewController : UITableViewController

@end

// .m

#import "ChecklistsViewController.h"

@interface ChecklistsViewController ()

@end

@implementation ChecklistsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];

    if (indexPath.row % 5 == 0) {
        label.text = @"Walk the dog";
    } else if (indexPath.row % 5 == 1) {
        label.text = @"Brush my teeth";
    } else if (indexPath.row % 5 == 2) {
        label.text = @"Learn iOS development";
    } else if (indexPath.row % 5 == 3) {
        label.text = @"Soccer practice";
    } else if (indexPath.row % 5 == 4)
        label.text = @"Eat ice cream";       

    return cell;
}

- tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}  // Control reaches end of non-function

@end
```

Comment: Where are you alloc-init the cell?

Comment: `- tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` should have a void in front of it..  **`-(void)tableView`**. BUt this shouldn't even let your build complete. Also, there is nothing in your code that would indicate a crash.

Comment: OK, the missing -(void) was the problem. Now it is OK. No idea why the build completed OK.

Answer (score 3):

In your example you do not allocate a `UITableViewCell` if none was dequeued. You need to do something like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"];
if( cell == nil ) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"] autorelease];

    // whatever additional initialization
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yo flex... working on your editorial rating :) Good idea, think I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate the `UITableViewCell` in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Your method should be like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UItableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UItableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   } 

//INSERT YOUR CODE

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UItableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UItableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   } 
//write your code here

return cell;

}
```